# Ranking data using a weight system

Tags: r, survey, ranking, scales, weights

I've collected data from 4 people (`id`) on their **number of violations** at work regarding (1) `logistics`, (2) doing `demos` for customers, and (3) achieving desired `outcomes`.

These violations were obtained using 3 items on logistics (`n_logistics`), 4 items on `demos` (`n_demos`), and 9 items on outcomes (`n_outcomes`).

Finally, `logistic` violations have a weight of $0.2$ (`w_logistics`), `demos` violations a weight of $0.3$ and `outcomes` violations a weight of $0.5$.

I was wondering how to fairly rank these 4 people from worst to best? (An `R` solution is appreciated.)

Data in `R` code:

```
data <- read.table(text="
id  logistics demos outcomes  n_logistics  n_demos   n_outcomes   w_logistics  w_demos   w_outcomes
1   2         0     5         3            4         9            .2           .3        .5
2   1         2     2         3            4         9            .2           .3        .5
3   0         0     7         3            4         9            .2           .3        .5
4   3         4     9         3            4         9            .2           .3        .5
", h=TRUE)
```